# Stream music from iPhone to another phone over Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, music, bluetooth, streaming, android

Can you send music data from your iPhone to Android with Bluetooth? I've got an Android Phone plug on my stereo and I want to use my iPhone to play music on it.

Is it possible?

Comment: As long as android can mimic a bluetooth headset, then the iPhone would see it as a valid music playing destination. Let's see if anyone here knows android or we could see if there is an android site to migrate if you prefer.

Comment: Thx for your answer !